# Get the current publish profile in C#

Tags: c#

I'm trying to write a c# condition based on which publish profile is being used. Pseudo code would look something like this:

```
if (Properties.Settings.PublishProfile1.isInUse)
    // Do something
else 
   //  Do something else
```

How can I get real code for this?

example of my partial class where I add my connection strings

#if DEBUG
connectionString = @"Server=dev.com; Database=dev; Integrated Security=true; MultipleActiveResultSets =true;"; //debug config

#elif QA
connectionString = @"Server=dev.com; Database=DBQA; Integrated Security=true; MultipleActiveResultSets =true;"; // QA config

#elif WEBDEPLOY
connectionString = @"Server=prod.com; Database=DB; User ID=user; Password=Password; Integrated Security=false; MultipleActiveResultSets =true;"; //web release config

#else
connectionString = @"Server=prod.com; Database=DB; Integrated Security=true; MultipleActiveResultSets =true;"; //release config

Comment: Is this .NET Core?  What version?  Are you using ASP.NET?

Comment: Could you describe your task? Most likely there are different ways to do what you want

Comment: What about when the code runs in a context that is nothing to do with publishing, which is almost all the time?

Comment: @TomW is right, I have never met a reason why you would need to do that check. Your publish profile just deploys your application to any location. Your application runs with a "build configuration" like `debug` or `release`. Sometimes there are reasons why you need to know whether the app is running in debug mode, then you could use `#if DEBUG`.

Comment: @RobertHarvey yes is .net 5

Comment: @AndrewSilver I use multiple configurations for my sln and each project. Then I use multiple DAL projects using repository pattern and UnitofWork. And them each application I publish I have to do a release version and a QA version but in this case, I'm using a specific configuration that is not using on the connection string Integrated Security but I don't want to keep creating sln /project configurations so I thought there is maybe a way to know which is the current publish configuration.

Comment: When you go to publish visual studio know which one was the last publish configuration and it opens that one. I basically one to know the same and for each case make a condition for it. Publishing QA goes to a different folder with different config, etc..

Comment: @TomW I think you may be right and there is probably no solution for this but if VS knows which one is currently in use it has to work similar to sln/project configurations which means I could technically approach my idea and use the publish config like the project or sln config. Remember after you compile this doesn't matter so tom the context wouldn't be affected.

Comment: So i wanted instead of creating a webdeployQA config use the publish configuration and change the connection string based on the publish config.